# Can life exist in intergalactic space?

Tags: astrophysics, biology, stellar-physics

A terrifying idea I think, to  be so utterly alone.

Do you reckon life could exist in intergalactic space? A lot of cosmic radiation is shielded from us by the Milky Way's magnetic field, but the stars of galaxies also create a lot of radiation, so maybe it would cancel out for a planetary system floating in intergalactic space.

Don't really see why not if its star is a high energy yellow dwarf.

I'm talking if about if the system was magically transported to intergalactic space, but as a second part to this question, how could such a system be ejected out into the void in the first place? Supernova?

Could life survive its planet being blasted out into intergalactic space? Could intelligent, advanced life, with foresight, be able to survive? What would they have to do to achieve this? Or could such a phenomenon happen gradually?

Comment: Since extraterrestrial life have never been shown to exist, how can this question be reasonably answered? I will just comment that an "ejection" as you mention is more likely from a gravitational interaction than from a supernova of some kind. But such planets have still never been observed.

Comment: I don't get why this was closed, so I'm voting to reopen. The question seems to be quite straightforwardly about whether there's so much radiation in intergalactic space that life could not survive on a planet located there. I don't think there's any sense in which the answer to that is "opinion based."

Comment: Particles in the intergalactic space interact only a very little, because $1 \frac{atom}{m^3}$ isn't too much. Life requires organized structures of matter, thus the answer is, on my opinion, no (to our the best knowledge).

Answer (score 7):

Whether any extraterrestrial life exists is pure speculation so we may indeed talk about the known theoretical arguments only, not about the empirical data.

From this theoretical viewpoint, it seems totally possible that life exists in the intergalactic space. After all, there exist intergalactic stars or rogue stars

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergalactic_star

that are moving in this space. Such stars may arguably have exoplanets, too.

The number of living planets orbiting intergalactic stars may be lower, especially if the theories about "panspermia" are right. These theories require some very primitive forms of life to be developed outside planets – in a process that took billions of years before the planets emerged. The intergalactic space has a very low density and therefore very low probability that such primitive life would "infect" those planets.

A completely different – and even more speculative – question is the life without stars of any kind. Life depends on processes out of thermal equilibrium. The Sun is able to heat the Earth's surface up to higher temperatures than the equilibrium temperature that the Earth approaches if it radiates the extra energy away. This temperature difference is key for the evolution of living structures because it's needed for them to get rid of entropy and become ordered.

There exist speculative proposals how this necessary physical ingredient for life could be replaced by something like "geothermal energy" and other ways. There also exist "industrial strategies" for the mankind to survive after the Sun goes red giant in 7.5 billion years. Of course that we don't really know whether any of these speculations are right or will be used or have been used by ETs or something like that. We don't know whether any of the scenarios are likely. They just seem compatible with the laws of physics as we know them.

It's rather natural to assume that any typical life form will be actually similar to ours – because ours represents 100% of the living civilizations we know so far which is a rather high percentage – so I am confident that most scientists do assume that other living planets may exist and they are qualitatively similar to Earth orbiting the Sun in a galaxy.

Answer (score 3):

Stars that exist outside of a galaxy were flung out by the gravitational disturbances when galaxies come too close, or collide with one another. I think it could be possible for life to theoretically exist provided the host planet had a sufficiently strong magnetic field to protect from cosmic radiation. There is nothing within a galaxy that protects us from its radiation - quite the contrary, there are many dangers, and vast swathes where life would be impossible. Given that radiation exposure reduces with distance I'd imagine life in these star systems would be safer - if very lonely.
It coUldale also be that any gravitational disturbance large enough to fling a star into intergalactic space would have a disruptive effect on the planetaryl positions and orbits to eradicate any existing life. who knows. All you can say with certainty is that their night sky would be extremely dark and empty.

Comment: A good point about radiation. There is indeed quite a bit of study around the idea that mass extinctions are quasi periodic and seem to co-incide with the solar system's oscillation through the galactic plane, *i.e.* through a region of increased potential for the kinds of radiation you suggest. Mostly this seems to be done by physicists; I'm not really sure how seriously paleontology really takes the idea.